# Repeating/alternating function arguments

Tags: typescript

**Is it possible to specify a function with a repeating pattern of input arguments?**

For example, if I want arguments to alternate between string and number

```
function someFunction(a: string, b: number){
  // 1 repetition
}
function someFunction(a: string, b: number, a2: string, b2: number){
  // 2 repetition
}
function someFunction(a: string, b: number, a2: string, b2: number, a3: string, b3: number){
  // 3 repetition
}
// and so on
```

It is of course possible to achieve something similar by a spread operator, but to my knowledge I cannot alternate the data type.

```
function someFunction(...someInput: (string|number)[]){
  // all input is now string|number, not string, then number, then string, and so on.
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  I would stick with overloads like you are doing.

Comment: This is definitely possible but not something I'd want to see in prod code.

Comment: It should in theory be infinitely large, which would cause some issues at some point.

Comment: @jcalz When you say "definitely possible", are you referring to using overloads, or as an answer to my question?

Comment: I was referring to an answer to your question without overloads.

Comment: Why not construct a datatype that contains a pair with a string and a number, then use the spread operator on that?

Comment: It is an external tool I'm trying to create typings for.

Comment: Why isn't it feasible to have `someFunction(a: number[], b: string[])` -- you have the same length of the input arrays. (Not denying your wish, I am trying to understand why you want that alternating input pattern from a real world use-case).

Comment: I overlooked your last comment. So basically, you have a pre-existing library that you cannot control but only can create typings for? Nevermind my question then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different approaches to this.  Here's one which kind of works and kind of doesn't.  There are possibly other ways to proceed also, but I'm pressed for time right now:

```
type SameLength<T> = { [K in keyof T]: any };
type Cyclic<T extends readonly any[], C extends readonly any[]> = readonly [] |
  (T extends [...SameLength<C>, ...infer U] ? readonly [...U, ...C] : readonly [...C]);

function someFunction<T extends readonly (string | number)[]>(
  ...args: T & Cyclic<T, [string, number]>
) { ... }
```

This should mostly work from the caller's side.  The idea is that the `args` parameter list will be checked against a shifted version of itself.  `Cyclic<[A, B, C, D], [string, number]` evaluates to `[C, D, string, number]`.  If `[A, B, C, D]` and `[C, D, string, number]` are the same, it means that it must be `[string, number, string, number]`.

Indeed, the function allows and disallows calls the way you want.

```
someFunction(); // okay
someFunction("a"); // error
someFunction("a", 1); // okay
someFunction("a", "b"); // error
someFunction("a", 1, "b", 2); // okay
someFunction("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3); // okay
```

Unfortunately the errors are not particularly informative, especially since they all show up on the first argument (which is a bug, [microsoft/TypeScript#28505](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28505)), and they complain about being assignable to `never`.  This *might* be addressable but I don't know how at the moment.

---

Inside the *implementation* of the function, it's worse.  The compiler does not know what type `T` will be and it can't reason generically that every other element will be a `string` and a `number`.  All you get is this:

```
function someFunction<T extends readonly (string | number)[]>(
  ...args: T & Cyclic<T, [string, number]>
) {
  const a = args[0] // string
  const b = args[1] // number
  const c = args[2] // string | number 
}
```

So inside the function you need to use an [assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or something like it to let the compiler know that `args[2*k]` is a `string | undefined` and `args[2*k+1]` is a `number | undefined`.

---

So this is not polished enough for me to advise using it in production code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyghgWwgGQgOwObABYB4AqAfFALxQDeUA2gNJQCWaUA1hCAPYBmU+AugFxQ4aEFAC+AbgBQoSFADCIAMYAbekoJQIAD2DoAJgGcoAJwhx97NCtHCQVXgBoFW3QeNmLVm0JEPiZJ6W1qIOUAA+UlBQABT4rnpoRtQAdGnwSKiYOLjyhM5pKYycECZQAKq8UAD8pubBPlSF5QVp8lWCQd6hhe0AlNJSnACuaErA9FZQhuxIAGKj45NomjqJyV0hsYbAJowYEVBowwgARqV9-jFRUIVwJhiGgvEAZArKahr4zlQ7e5jOY5nUq8QhSPoUKQ3JRWHZCUhCB6GKgABiqAHp0dNdvtobDgFBTgj7o8qABGDFYoHnEx4tBwpTEpFUABMlOx-wO4SOJxpUEAvBuAIj2oWIoTN5osJlYYgMoJioOxmHAQFJxRAFmMpWgYgAiOA62Xy0omdi0tUapbSvU65xkw1YxXK1WzdWS5a6-XOHWnA0SOVY42m50SzXu622r0+5ws+0KpUq81uq2eqBkyM2qAsr1KDMAZljjpVUiAA)

---

EDIT:

the following is a link to a slightly different formulation which has similar issues; the error messages are less opaque  but it requires circular conditional types that won't be supported until TS4.1 and it's a bit more convoluted to explain.  Not sure it's worth explaining this one when it's not much of an improvement over the other:

```
type StringNumberAlternating<L extends number,
  A extends readonly any[] = readonly []> = (string | number)[] & (
    undefined extends [...A][L] ? A['length'] extends L ? A :
    StringNumberAlternating<L, [string, number, ...A]> : A)

function someFunction<T extends StringNumberAlternating<T['length']>>(
  ...args: T
) { }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-insiders.20201010#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)

---

UPDATE: you can also do it this way (in TS4.1+) where you pick a finite maximum argument list length (say, 20) and generate the union of relevant alternating tuples:

```
type SN<T extends readonly any[] = readonly []> = readonly [] | readonly [string, number, ...T]
type SNT<L extends number, A extends readonly any[] = readonly []> =
  A | (A['length'] extends L ? never : SNT<L, readonly [string, number, ...A]>);
type StringNumberTuples = SNT<20>; // max length of 20

function someFunction(...args: StringNumberTuples) {
  const a = args[0] // string | undefined
  const b = args[1] // number | undefined
  const c = args[2] // string | undefined
  const d = args[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)] // string | number ‍♂️
}
```

This has good error messages (except they are still on the first argument all the time, due to microsoft/TypeScript#28505), and the function signature is no longer generic and is thus simpler.  The main limitation is that you have to pick some maximum length to support; it's sort of like using overloads, except you can just pass a number like 20 instead of writing 10 overload signatures.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-insiders.20201010#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-iwAXwe31+ANe70ott2ZPIAGsSCALFH-oC4yCAEQkXMjfaHQyEE0Zn5Z2PA5L53MaLlFpOp9OZmNA+N1jS5vSFxMlwhlwgV6PZmtdx3d3sadZNw4ptMjqsdvMFhtT+t3bsvTcAZjnVxbDyAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exceptional. I'm wrangling with a database adapter which is trying to be 1-to-1 with the database query language, so this can definitely help with the typings.

Comment: edited to add a slightly different formulation which isn't really much better.

Comment: Above and beyond. Thanks a lot!